# Why can't a recursive-descent parser handle left recursion

Tags: parsing, theory

Could someone please explain to me why recursive-descent parsers can't work with a grammar containing left recursion?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

consider:

```
A ::= A B
```

the equivalent code is

```
boolean A() {
    if (A()) {
        return B();
    }
    return false;
}
```

see the infinite recursion?

Answer (score 22):

For whoever is interested

```
 A ::= A B | A C | D | E
```

can be rewritten as:

```
 A ::= (D | E) (B | C)*
```

The general form of the transformation is: any one of the non left recursive disjuncts followed by any number of the left recursive disjuncts without the first element.

Reforming the action code is a bit trickery but I thing that can be plug-n-chug as well.

Comment: First time I've seen that, I always saw advice to use a new non-terminal, usually called A'

Comment: Well some BNF based tools won't allow () groups so you end up stuck with the new rule solution. I'm kinda partial to the form I proposed because my parser generator needs to do the action transformation as well so it's a lot easier to make it work without a new rule.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question. Would be better as a comment.

Comment: @Kristopher: Check the date, IIRC the comment size limit was way to small for this back then.

Comment: I ended up figuring this out myself by going over the code in my head, glad to see a sort of confirmation I got it right!