# ask for a parser grammar, using boost spirit qi is better

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to use `boost::spirit::qi` to parse an expression.

The expression is simple, it can be

1. id, like `x`
2. member of an object, like `obj.x`
3. an element of an array, like `arr[2]`
4. a result of function call. `func(x, y)`

A member of object can be array or function type so
`x.y[2]`, `x.y()` are legal.

A function result might be an array or object
so `func(x,y).value`, `func(x)[4]` are legal too.

An array element might be object or function type
so `arr[5].y`, `arr[3](x, y)` are legal.

Combined together, the following expression should be legal:

`x[1]().y(x, y, x.z, z[4].y)().q[2][3].fun()[5].x.y.z`

All these `[...]` `(...)` and `.` has same precedence and from left to right.

My grammar like this

```
expression
    = postfix_expr
    | member_expr
    ;

postfix_expr = elem_expr | call_expr | id;
elem_expr = postfix_expr >> "[" >> qi::int_ >> "]";
call_expr = postfix_expr >> "(" >> expression_list >> ")";
member_expr = id >> *("." >> member_expr);

expression_list
    = -(expression % ",")
```

but it always crashes, I think maybe somewhere has infinity loop.

Please give me some suggestion on how to parse this grammar.

**EDIT**
**FOLLOW UP QUESTION:**
thanks cadrian, it works!

now expression can parse correctly, but I want to introduce a new `ref_exp`
which is an expression too, but not end with `()` because function result cannot be placed to left of assignment.

my definition is :

```
    ref_exp
        = id
        | (id >> *postfix_exp >> (memb_exp | elem_exp))
        ;

    postfix_exp
        = memb_exp
        | elem_exp
        | call_exp
        ;

    memb_exp = "." >> id;
    elem_exp = "[" >> qi::uint_ >> "]";
    call_exp = ("(" >> expression_list >> ")");
```

but `boost::spirit::qi` cannot parse this,
I think the reason is `(memb_exp | elem_exp)` is part of `postfix_exp`, how to make it not parse all, and leave the very last part to match `(memb_exp | elem_exp)`

`ref_exp` examples: `x`, `x.y`, `x()[12][21]`, `f(x, y, z).x[2]`
not `ref_exp` : `f()`, `x.y()`, `x[12]()`

Comment: I suggest you post the follow up separate. I'm happy to look at it **iff** you can include a working sample (even if it demonstrates the problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`boost::spirit::qi` [is a descending parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spirit_Parser_Framework); your grammar *must not* be left recursive.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847439/why-cant-a-recursive-descent-parser-handle-left-recursion/847455).

Here you definitely have a left-recursive grammar: `postfix_expr -> elem_expr  -> postfix_expr`

**EDIT** One way to fix this.

As I see it, your expression is a string of ids with possible suffixes: `[]`, `()`, `.`.

```
expression = id >> *cont_expr;
cont_expr = elem_expr | call_expr | member_expr
elem_expr = "[" >> qi::int_ >> "]";
call_expr = "(" >> expression_list >> ")";
member_expr = "." >> expression;
expression_list = -(expression % ",")
```

**EDIT 2** If you want to be able to force precedence – for instance with parentheses:

```
expression = prefix_expr >> *cont_expr;
prefix_expr = id | par_expr
par_expr = "(" >> expression >> ")"
```

This way you could even write expressions like `x.(y[3].foo)[5](fun(), foo(bar))` – if that makes sense.

**EDIT 3** I answer to your comment here.

You need the left side of assignments not to be functions. That means that you have a specific suffix for left-hand expressions. Let's call that rule `ref_exp` as in your comment.

```
ref_exp = id >> -( *cont_expr >> cont_ref );
cont_ref = elem_expr | member_expr;
```

Comment: yes, it works, but I have one more follow up question. because function result can not place to left of assignment, when a new `ref_exp` introduced, how do I tell an expression end with `id` or `[]` is `ref_exp`

Comment: this does not work, I tried before. for example `f[2].y()`, `*cont_expr` will match all `[2]`, `.y` and `()`, when it parses to `cont_ref`, nothing left, and parse fail

Comment: Ouch. You are right, I introduced non-determinism :-/

Answer (score 2):

finally I think I solve this problem, but this solution has a side-effects, it will change operator associativity.

```
    lvalue_exp
        = id >> -(ref_exp);
        ;

    ref_exp
        = (postfix_exp >> ref_exp)
        | memb_exp
        | elem_exp
        ;

    postfix_exp
        = call_exp
        | memb_exp
        | elem_exp
        ;

    memb_exp
        = ("." >> id)
        ;

    elem_exp
        = ("[" >> qi::uint_ >> "]")
        ;

    call_exp
        = ("(" >> expression_list >> ")")
        ;
```

so for the expression `f().y()[0]` will parse like:

1. `f` and `ref_exp` - `().y()[0]`
2. `().y()[0]` parsed as `().y()` and `[0]`
3. `().y()` parsed as `()` and `.y()`
4. `.y()` parsed as `.y` and `()`

if I do not distinguish lvalue

`f().y()[0]` will parse like:

1. `f` and `().y()[0]`
2. `()` and `.y()[0]`
3. `.y` and `()[0]`
4. `()` and `[0]`

so I will use second one and check reference when I generate the ast.

Thanks @cadrian