# Succinct grammar to parse strings of alternating characters like "ababa" or "baba"

Tags: parsing, go

I am working on a toy [parser](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser) in [golang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Go_(programming_language)) just to learn the language. I added a test case with grammar covering the following cases:

```
Valid:
a, ab, aba, ababababababa, ababababab
b, ba, bab, babababababab, bababababa

Invalid:
abb, baa
```

`a` is always followed by `b` and vice versa.

Now the grammar in my parser looks like that (I omit the surrounding code for sake of brevity):

```
    "expr": Or(Ref("A"), Ref("B")),
    "A": And(
        a,
        Optional(
            And(
                b,
                Optional(Ref("A"))))),
    "B": And(
        b,
        Optional(Ref("A")))
```

Where

```
a - exact match for "a" character
b - exact match for "b" character
"A", "B", "expr" - names of the parts of the grammar that can be referred
                   later with Ref("A")
And      - consume sequence of expressions
Or       - consume any of the expressions
Ref      - refer to other expression (allows recursion)
Optional - make the expression non-obligatory
```

I guess it is not the most succinct way to describe this grammar. How to make it more compact?

Related:

- [Why can't a recursive-descent parser handle left recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/847439/why-cant-a-recursive-descent-parser-handle-left-recursion)

---

EDIT:

The BNF [answer from Filip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34954618/497208) can be written in my syntax as:

```
    "expr": Or(Ref("A"), Ref("B")),
    "A":    Or(And(a, Ref("B")), a),
    "B":    Or(And(b, Ref("A")), b)
```

Comment: @DenysSéguret: not sure. It is not really about golang but more about parsers and grammar.

Comment: @DenysSéguret If it's on-topic here, let it stick here. No point in moving something if it's on-topic here as well.

Comment: @DenysSéguret There is no code in this question to review.

Comment: As a regular expression, that language is `a?(ba)*b?` but I don't think that helps you parse it with an RDP. (Yes, it is also `b?(ab)*a?` Curiously, the two regular expressions are equivalent.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BNF grammar you have is this:

```
expr ::= A | B
A ::= "a" B | "a"
B ::= "b" A | "b"
```

which I think translates to this using your syntax:

```
"expr": Or(Ref("A"), Ref("B")),
"A": And(
    a,
    Optional(Ref("B"))),
"B": And(
    b,
    Optional(Ref("A")))
```

Note that it is important to check terminals (`"a"`, `"b"`) before non-terminals (`Ref(x)`), or you'll get an infinite loop. It would always try to see if it could match another `A` or `B` to the end of the string, and then another, and another, causing a never ending recursion.

Comment: Would be better written as `A ::= "a" B?`

Comment: If I remove the extra ` | "a"` case, how would it terminate?

Comment: (and why doesn't ` | "a"` render as a code snippet?)

Comment: @Filip: In a comment, ` is only special if not followed by a space.

Comment: @FilipHaglund: Your answer in my syntax and in BNF both works, I edited my post where I translate your BNF to my syntax